# Open a dynamic image in modal (pop up)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am retrieving the path of an image source from MySQL in a list. I want to open this image (preview) in a Bootstrap modal but it isn't getting the correct image.

Here is my PHP code:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM  `dirf1` WHERE  `root` =  '$root' AND  `pId` =  '$pid' ORDER BY fileType";
    $result_set=mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result_set))
    {
              <td><a href="f/'.$row['fileName'].'"><?php echo $link; ?><i style="font-size:22px; color:#FF9900;"></i> &emsp; <?php echo $row['fileName'] ?></a></td>
}
```

Here is my Bootstrap modal code:

```
<!-- Modal image preview  -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" align="center">Image</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="f/<?php echo $showName; ?>" height="100%" width="100%" >
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div> <!-- modal image preview  end -->
```

How can I open a dynamic image in a Bootstrap modal?

Comment: can you please help ? https://stackoverflow.com/users/1213708/nigel-ren

Comment: If it isn't getting the correct image name, then no front-end help at all will help. In that case, there's something wrong in either your SQL or your PHP.

Comment: its echo the correct name in table but in modal only first result show . query is working correct . can you please review this code ? @Snowmonkey

Comment: So you're looking to have a modal that will display the image, when the user selects it from a given td element? In that case, what is the javascript you have popping up the modal?

Comment: i am using default modal of bootstrap it dose'nt need any external javascript code. @Snowmonkey

Comment: So tell me -- how exactly does bootstrap know that THIS particular td is to pop up the modal, and what its content is to be? Bootstrap will pop up the modal, to be sure, but you haven't told bootstrap to use that image for its content. That's the missing piece.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @Snowmonkey i have tried this but dosent work .

Comment: ...and that's the question. What have you tried? What is your javascript for this?

Comment: @Snowmonkey do you ever tried bootstrap modal. i am telling you again bootstrap modal dosent need external javascript code.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood. I assumed you had a single modal, and you were populating that with the new image prior to display. From your irrational reaction, I would now assume you're creating a modal for each and every image? In that case, having the same id assigned to every one would break. If, instead, you're trying to use a single modal and have that update with a dynamic image, yes you WILL in fact need some "external javascript code." Best of luck. Try to be more clear in your questions. Downvote.

Comment: My advice? research data-* attributes to your modal triggers. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content

Comment: Oh never mind. Bootstrap itself tells you to use an external javascript. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I repeatedly said in my notes, you DO NOT need any other javascript to pop up a modal. You're absolutely right. If, however, you want to have DYNAMIC content inserted into the modal, then I was right in that you DO need some sort of external control. If you followed the link to the bootstrap documentation, you would have seen something very like the following:

```js
/****
 * When the modal is displayed, I want to get my dynamic content.
 *  In this case, the dynamic content is a data-whatever attribute
 *  and the actual text content of the clicked LI element.
 *
 *  I will take that content, and use it to populate my modal
 *  dynamically. In this way, I have a single modal popup with content
 *  from any number of sources. The only requirements are that the
 *  triggering element have a data-whatever attribute and some
 *  sort of text content.
 *  All of this is happening when my modal is triggering its show
 *  event, so it will all happen just before the modal is displayed.
 ****/
 
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  // Element that triggered the modal
  var liEl = $(event.relatedTarget); 
  
   // Extract info from data-* attributes, and from the element itself.
  var recipient = liEl.data('whatever');
  var textContent = liEl.text();
  
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here
  //   (and then do the updating in a callback).
  // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could
  //   use a data binding library or other methods instead.
  var modal = $(this);
  
  // Update the dynamic portions of the modal dialog.
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient);
  modal.find('.modal-body textarea[name="message-body"]').text(textContent);
});
```

```css
.js-my-modal-control {
  width: 300px;
}
.js-my-modal-control li{
  cursor: pointer;
}
.js-my-modal-control li:hover{
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.modal textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="js-my-modal-control list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-whatever="andrej@foo.bar">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-whatever="boris@foo.bar">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-whatever="cherise@foo.bar">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-whatever="daoud@foo.bar">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-whatever="esteban@foo.bar">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>

<!-- Modal which I will be filling with dynamic content -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <textarea name='message-body'></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Note that the dialog itself is being handled by Bootstrap. I have NOTHING to do with it. I leave that piece alone, as it works fine. But I can and SHOULD hook into the Bootstrap API and listen for the modal's `show.bs.modal` event -- at this point, I want to refer back to the triggering element, get its content, and populate my single modal. THIS IS THE DYNAMIC BIT.

And to answer your question, yes. Yes I have had extensive experience with bootstrap. Have you?

Comment: I apologise for being a bit sarcastic in my response, but truly glad it works. ;)